# How to access the api docs with swagger

Tags: api, swagger, dropwizard

I have followed the same exact steps from this doc http://mikelynchgames.com/software-development/adding-swagger-to-your-dropwizard-application/

How do I access the doc I've written for the resources. Here is te yaml file

```
swaggerBasePath: 
  http://localhost:9080
```

whats the postfix to this url?

Comment: It would be good to share the relative code then the link

Answer (score 0):

I use the smoketurner bundle and it is working well

https://github.com/smoketurner/dropwizard-swagger

When you launch your dropwizard application

```
    INFO  [2017-03-23 04:10:03,931] [main] [DropwizardResourceConfig]: The following paths were found for the configured resources:

    GET     /swagger (io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource)
    GET     /swagger.{type:json|yaml} (io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource)
```

Comment: What version of dropwizrd are you using ? i am on 0.8 and it's running into some issues

Comment: Thank you!! I had a conflicting dependency otherwise works great